# Android Hardware-backed KeyStore

Tags: android-keystore

I am interested in the hardware-backed KeyStore. I was looking at some documentation and I have noticed some contradiction.

The official documentation ([here](https://source.android.com/security/keystore/features.html)) confirms that all implementations must provide, among others, AES encryption.

Multiple implementations exist for the KeyStore. I looked at the Qualcomm one that is based on QSEE. As far as I understood from The keymaster glue ([here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/hardware/qcom/keymaster/+/master/keymaster_qcom.cpp)), the QSEE-based KeyStore implements only RSA encryption.

Am I missing something ? I am considering the case that this keymaster glue is not up-to-date. In this case, where can I find the latest one ?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: just curious to know , since hardware based keystore is supported only on > M version --> How will it be helpful. Just trying to understand  your use case.